# VBA regex to find special characters in reverse

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I'm trying to find special characters in a cell using the below code. However, still not getting desired out.

i created the regex in reverse, where it will allow few special characters and alpha numeric, as we don't know/have the special characters list.

```css
Function spltrack(cell As String)

'Use Regular Expressiosn for grabbing the input and automatically filter it
Dim regEx As New RegExp

With regEx
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    
    .Pattern = "[0-9][a-zA-Z]|(\[\]())|.+-/|'&%#_:,!–"
End With

If regEx.Test(cell) Then
    spltrack = "Not Found"
Else
    spltrack = "Found"
End If


End Function
```

Is anything wrong with code or any other better way?

> [image]

Comment: Do you have sample data with expected results?

Comment: Yes here it is https://gofile.io/d/kWXwZA

Comment: Please include sample data we don't have to download into the OP

Comment: Added as image please check

Comment: Please read the comment of JvdV again. Include sample data, that does NOT mean add an image, we can't copy the data from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to return *true* if there are characters other than letters, digits and whitespace:

```
With regEx
    .Pattern = "[^0-9a-zA-Z\s()[\]:'""/&%#!_+,.|-]"
End With

If regEx.Test(cell) Then
    spltrack = "Found"
Else
    spltrack = "Not Found"
End If
```

**Explanation**

```
                         EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^0-9a-zA-                any character except: '0' to '9', 'a' to
  Z\s()[\]:'"/&%#!_+,.     'z', 'A' to 'Z', whitespace (\n, \r, \t,
  |-]                      \f, and " "), '(', ')', '[', '\]', ':',
                           ''', '"', '/', '&', '%', '#', '!', '_',
                           '+', ',', '.', '|', '-'
```

Comment: thank you so much. I need to add the following char. as well, for which i,m facing the challenge.. () [] : ' " / & % # ! - _ + , . |

Comment: @Linga Updated.